# which logger to use when using getlogger?

Tags: java, log4j, log4net

I have two loggers :

1. root and
2. test1

If I use `getlogger("test1")`, it will use test1, is that right?

when using `getlogger(typeof(Program))`, will it use root?

Answer (score 0):

The logger that is used is defined in your log4j.properties/log4j.xml and that is based on the name of your package.

The getLogger(name) is used to log the name of the current class.

If you input "test1" as a parameter, the log4j log line for your call will contain the "test1".

Answer (score 0):

When you do `getLogger("test1")` it will use the logger named test1.

When using `getLogger(class)`, it will retrieve the logger that has been named using the class name.

If you are trying to get root logger, use `getRootLogger()` instead.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29 for more

Your class should use root by default depending on your configuration. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

"As a side note, let me mention that in log4j child loggers link only to their existing ancestors. In particular, the logger named com.foo.Bar is linked directly to the root logger, thereby circumventing the unused com or com.foo loggers. This significantly increases performance and reduces log4j's memory footprint." - from the manual